# Java / Netbeans Build Successful but println not displayed

Tags: java, netbeans

So I'm using netbeans to start writing some Java.  I've created a project called "Java21" and within it I have a VolcanoRobot.java file (this is just a class), VolcanoApplication.java (this is what I'm trying to run), and then the Java21.java file (that I assume is just created upon creating the project.

Here's my VolcanoApplication.java file:

```
class VolcanoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        VolcanoRobot dante = new VolcanoRobot();
        dante.status = "exploring";
        dante.speed = 2;
        dante.temperature = 510;
        dante.showAttributes();
        System.out.println("Increasing speed to 3.");
        dante.speed = 3;
        dante.showAttributes();
        System.out.println("Changing temperature to 670.");
        dante.temperature = 670;
        dante.showAttributes();
        System.out.println("Checking the temperature.");
        dante.checkTemperature();
        dante.showAttributes();
    }
}
```

At any rate, when I click "run project", the output pane says "BUILD SUCCESSFUL", but there's none of the text that the above code should spit out (from System.out.println...)

Have a feeling this has to do with having two "main" methods but any help much appreciated!

Thanks,
Mariogs

Comment: Yes, that might be a fair assumption. Where are those two methods located? And what class are you exactly executing from?

Comment: Is your project the default project in the netbeans ?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: When there is no error, no exception, etc. what difference would it make where those methods are located ?

Comment: @CMonster: because it is a step in the process of determining the problem. He could be executing the wrong project and he could be executing the wrong `main` method that's located in two classes in his   project.

Comment: You told it to create a `main()` when you created the project, and it did so, and that's what's in `java21.java` and what is getting run. You need to delete that file.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: you are right about the main method, I though you were talking about the ones at the end of the code.

Comment: So in general, when I create a project called "X", I'll get X.java with a main method?  So I shouldn't create a main method in any other file within the project?

Comment: @BrianRoach Not totally sure what you mean by "you told it to create a "main()" when you created the project.  Was that one of the defaults I just missed / accepted?

Comment: @Mariogs Yes- the wizard has a checkbox for it when you create the project. Something like "create class with main()` ... I'd have to fire up netbeans to get the exact wording. If you delete that file, it should then pick up your main in your class.

Comment: @CMonster: the `main` method can go anywhere, it is not restricted to a class.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Sorry I confused it with name of the class that must be the same as the filename :P That mean I have to stop to commenting when I haven't had enough sleep :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kind of hard to see without seeing your Netbeans setup, but if you are clicking run project and your project has more than one class containing a main method, it's probably running the wrong class. Try right-clicking VolcanoApplication.java directly and running that and see if it makes a difference.